# Angular 2 Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

What am I doing wrong?

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `{{title}}`
})
export class App {
  title = "Angular 2 beta";
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
}
```

main.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

The error is

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The class name doesn't match what you are bootstrapping.  I.e., instead of

```
export class App { ... }
```

use

```
export class AppComponent { ... }
```

---

Angular is trying to find the `annotations` property of a class named `AppComponent`, but that class doesn't exist, hence the error.

Comment: This error is so tricky. It should simply say that `'App' is not found` Whenever I make an example in plunker, I ran into this error, and I spent quite time to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Sadly, you get what you pay for when you use Angular. Google does not seem interested whatsoever in providing helpful error messages.

Comment: I don't think Angular devs don't want to provide helpful error messages, I think they just over estimate the average devs understanding of angular 2 and how quickly we will figure out the details. They just know their code and assume we do too.

Comment: It could be a little bit more tricky as it could also be an old import. I had a similar issue caused by a component which imported a non existing component. I do not know why I didn't get any errors while testing in my browser but got one when deploying to native.